# How to redirect to an action method of another area within OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

In My MVC5 application I have 3 areas. My project structure as following

[image]

I have implemented an ActionFilter class to validate whether user has granted the permission for particular action methods. My ActionFilter class stay out of areas folder. I want to check user permission within the OnActionExecuting method and redirect to PermissionDenied action method which has implemented on ErrorControl. However it does not recognize within areas and gives an error message mentioning "No controller and action method found within the area"

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {


        if(!GrantPermission(filterContext))
        {
            Controller contr = (BaseController)filterContext.Controller;
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "area", "" },
                    { "controller",  "Error" },
                    { "action", "PermissionDenied" } 
            });
            filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(contr.ControllerContext);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);


    }
```

Can anyone help me to get this solved. this one already has ruined my day.

Answer (score 0):

Area is not a route value. It is put into the `RouteData.DataTokens` dictionary instead. But there is no way to set it from `RedirectToRouteResult`.

Instead, you could use the `UrlHelper` to generate the URL much as you would in an `ActionLink`. The `UrlHelper` will work out what the virtual path of your `Area` is. Then, you can just use `RedirectResult` to get to that URL.

```
if (!GrantPermission(filterContext))
{
    Controller contr = (BaseController)filterContext.Controller;

    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
    var redirectUrl = urlHelper.Action("PermissionDenied", "Error", new { area = "" });
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl);
    filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(contr.ControllerContext);
}

base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
```

> **NOTE:** The correct way to authorize an action is to use either [`IAuthorizationFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter(v=vs.118).aspx) or better yet, inherit [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx). Authorization filters run before action filters do. Also, they will execute the result handler automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and the suggestion it will really helpful me. I tried this code but it  always sets null for redirectUrl    var redirectUrl = urlHelper.Action("PermissionDenied", "Error", new { area = "" });